# Is Delta (as in change in a quantity) a rigorous mathematical concept?

Tags: calculus

To my understanding (heavily biased by physics), $\Delta$ is often and seemingly only used to eventually use the fundemental theorem of calculus. For example, let's say we have an arbitrary change in temperature. Then, we denote that as $\Delta{T}$. Then, after establishing this first case for a given situation, I often see the limit being taken of $\Delta$ quantities to create a $dT$ quantity (an infinitesimal) so we can integrate and etc.

Now, I understand that the fundamental theorem of calculus explicitly uses $\Delta$ along with the limit taking mentioned above. So, it seems like it is a serious mathematical concept, but using $\Delta$ feels very hand-wavey or imprecise, if that makes sense.

Any help or pointing to resources would be much appreciated.

Comment: In mathematics (specifically analysis) $\Delta$ often represents a small change, but we then consider limits as $\Delta \to 0$. This is very rigorous and not imprecise at all. In physics, we often allow $\Delta$ to be small but finite and then think about what might follow for the assumption of smallness this fine, but you have to ask yourself whether what you are doing is justified. For example, if we use a Taylor series and throw away all of the terms after a certain point, we are making a judgment which may or may not be ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\Delta$ isn't really a concept, it's just a symbol. For example, the definition of a derivative can be written like so:

$$f'(x) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x+\Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x},$$

but in this equation, $\Delta$ is not really a concept, it's just part of the symboll combination "$\Delta x$" that is just some variable denoting a real number. That's all. The above equation is equally valid if I write it as

$$f'(x) = \lim_{\mathrm{elephant} \to 0} \frac{f(x+\mathrm{elephant}) - f(x)}{\mathrm{elephant}}.$$

---

That said, it's a symbol that usually denotes the change of... something. And as long as it is used unambiguously and clearly, the symbol $\Delta$ can make a lot of things easier to understand. For example, one can **define** a shorthand notation and say that for any function $f$ and any real value $\Delta x$, the function $\Delta f$ is the function $x\mapsto f(x+\Delta x) - f(x)$. Note that this notation is usually not *explicitly* defined in the text, but the definition is clear and unambiguous from context.

Also note that using this notation, the definition of the derivative becomes

$$f'(x) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{\Delta f(x)}{\Delta x}$$

which is nice because it really gives the intuition behind why $f'(x)$ is often written as $\frac{df}{dx}$.

Comment: (+1) for "elephant" usage. It might be worth mentioning that $\Delta$ can be considered [by itself as an operator on sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#difference_operator) that has formal algebraic similarities to the differentiation operator on functions, but in the present context (in agreement with what you said) it's best not to mathematically disentangle the symbol $\Delta$ from what follows it, but instead think of it as a kind of "mathematical prefix" part of a variable (analogous to "sub" as a linguistic prefix to the words **sub**way and **sub**marine).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Agreed. This is more a comment to the OP now: My answer describes **one** particular usage of the symbol $\Delta$, in particular, the usage that explains its connection to derivatives.  There are other uses of the symbol in other fields of mathematics. That's nothing unusual, of course. Most mathematical symbols have more than one meaning. $\partial$, for example may be used in analysis to denote partial derivatives, or in topology to denote the edges of manifolds.